# Quelle est la difference entre "les chiennes blanc et noir" et "les chiennes blanches et noires"? Écrit-on "les vert olive" ou "les verts olives"?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, orthographe, accord, francais-classique

Sachant que les adjectifs de couleur ne s'accorde pas quand ils sont composés. Met-on "les vert olive" ou "les verts olive"? Car techniquement dans cette situation, "vert" n'est pas un adjectif mais un nom.

Et puis, met-on "des bleu**s** clair**s** et foncé**s**", "des bleu**s** clair et foncé" ou "des bleu clair et foncé"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour les chiennes, voir la [réponse de Fréfré](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50700/1109).

*Les vert**s** olive* : puisque vert est un nom commun ici.

*Des bleu**s** clair**s** et foncé**s*** : des bleus clairs et des bleus foncés.

*Des bleu**s** clair et foncé* : discutable, des bleus différents mais ayant en commun le fait d'être à la fois clairs et foncés...

*<s>Des bleu clair et foncé</s>* : faute d'accord.

Answer (score 5):

Les chiennes blanc et noir = les chiennes ont chacune les 2 couleurs

Les chiennes blanches et noires = les chiennes de couleur blanche et les chiennes de couleur noire.